# It seems like the math of arduino is off

Tags: arduino-ide, arduino-pro-mini, accelerometer, gyroscope, mathematics

*[SOLVED] By changing the offset for the incoming data into `int16_t` type there won't be any rounding errors and the values I'm getting are all back to zero in the sensor its base position*

This is my first project where I use Arduino.

Until today everything went good with the Arduino Pro Mini (3.3v).
But as of today I got a bit of a weird problem.
I am using a MPU gy-521 (doesn't really matter) and I'm working on calculating the actual movement.

The problem which occured is that I'm using a deadzone to negate the smallest numbers (I know, this isn't the right way to use data). The way I negate the numbers is with the following code

```
// Check deadzone values
  if (ax+axo < adz && ax+axo > -adz) ax = -axo;
  if (ay+ayo < adz && ay+ayo > -adz) ay = -ayo;
  if (az+azo < adz && az+azo > -adz) az = -azo;

  if (gx+gxo < gdz && gx+gxo > -gdz) gx = -gxo;
  if (gy+gyo < gdz && gy+gyo > -gdz) gy = -gyo;
  if (gz+gzo < gdz && gz+gzo > -gdz) gz = -gzo;
```

ax is accelerometer data over the x-axis, axo is the offset, adz is the accelerometer deadzone.

gx is gyroscope data over the x-axis, gxo is the offset, gdz is the gyroscope deadzone.

All of the other letters are the same, for different axis.
After getting the values within the offset basically set to 0 with the offset I'm doing the following.

```
// Calculate acceleration
  axa = (ax+axo) / aFactor * g;
  aya = (ay+ayo) / aFactor * g;
  aza = (az+azo) / aFactor * g;

  gxa = (gx+gxo) / gFactor;
  gya = (gy+gyo) / gFactor;
  gza = (gz+gzo) / gFactor;
```

The a- and gFactor are mentioned in the datasheet, but these values should all be 0 if the value of axis plus the offset is within the deadzone.
The problem is that I'm not just getting 0.00 values.
I'm also getting -0.00 and 0.01.

```
0.00    0.00    -0.00   0.00    0.01    0.01
```

Could someone enlighten me about what's wrong in my situation or if this is just a Arduino issue.

*[EDIT]*

The data originally from the sensor is from type int16_t (ax, ay, az, gx, gy, gz) and the other variables are doubles.

The values which are off are always the same ones: Accelerometer Z, Gyroscope Y and Z.

Comment: Are all your variables declared as `float` ('axa, axo, aFactor, g, ...`) ?

Comment: The variables are all declared as `double` except for the ax, ay, az values which are `int16_t` by default

Comment: What are changes between _**"Until today everything went"**_ and _**"today I got a bit of a weird problem"**_ (source code, sensors, wiring, other) ?

Comment: Change axo etc... to also be `int16_t` rather than floats. That way when you set `ax = -axo;` and then do `(ax+axo)` there is no risk of rounding errors converting from double to int and back, you should always get exactly 0.

Comment: If `axo` is not an integer, then the statement `ax = -axo;` will perform rounding, and the expression `ax+axo` will be non-zero.

Comment: Iirc before today I was just getting zero's which was fine for me. Since then I removed the wiring and place them back (same setup) mostly the same code, atleast it shouldnt have changed the output.

When I change all of my variables into `into16_t` I just get zero's as output, no decimals. Since I'm working with dt precision I can't have this.

I fixed it by just setting the `axo` variable to `int16_t`, Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your program is basically working but gives you rounding errors, it can be that you are facing some problems related to conversion from floating-point to binary or reverse. It is a very common problem in computer science. For example, the decimal number `0.1` has no exact binary  representation, it is infinite. For more information, you can read these pages:

http://www.exploringbinary.com/why-0-point-1-does-not-exist-in-floating-point/
https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/datarepresentation.html

In order to solve your problem, you can try to apply appropriate rounding to your results and if possible avoid mixing different data types and use `double` only if absolutely needed (which I guess is the case in your application).